# Toolbar not showing in app

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I feel stupid asking this but I probably spend 6 hours straight trying to figure this out. 
I can't get my toolbar to show up in the app at all - implemented as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="de.gymnasium_beetzendorf.vertretungsplan.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now my MainActivity code looks like that:

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mainToolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

My style.xml looks like this(which is identical to a style.xml that Android Studio creates when creating an Application with an empty activity):

```
<resources>
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

The only thing I have to add are the last two items(windowActionBar, windowNoTitle) because else the app crashes when running it.

One thing I noticed that might be helpful for others (they're not for me): 
When I check mToolbar == null it returns true - don't know why. The call is after setContentView.

Manifest as requested(I left out all the other activites):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.gymnasium_beetzendorf.vertretungsplan">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? 
It looks pretty standard but I can't figure out what it is. Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: lets see the manifest as well @Crosswind

Comment: forgot about that, edited the post @SalvatoryBaya

Comment: is your code on github? i can help you debug. I cannot still find a problem yet based on the provided info.

Comment: right there - https://github.com/Crosswind/Vertretungsplan Thanks for you effort! @SalvatoryBaya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked your code at GitHub.

You have layout-v21\activity_main.xml file. This file doesn't has a toolbar. So, if you test the app on devices with Android 5.0+ you do not see the toolbar. You need to add the toolbar to this activity too to see it on all devices.

Comment: @Crosswind Alexey is right, thats what i've noticed myself. I was about to post the reply

Comment: Okay, no idea why that was there. Thanks guys!